# Как элементы кортежа в Python разобрать на отдельные аргументы функции?

Tags: python, tuple, кортежи

И здесь еще одно условие: элементы кортежа - это файлы, а функция требует подавать в нее аргументы строками (именами файлов).

Итак, есть набор папок `spk1`, `spk2` и т.д., в них лежат по 2-4 файла каждого спикера (всякая папка содержит файлы с высказываниями одного и того же говорящего; и так - 11 говорящих). Моя конечная задача сопоставить голоса в каждой на схожесть (причем только в пределах своей папки: сравниваю человека с самим собой).

Ранее мне подсказали здесь (спасибо!) - и я получил кортежи с перебором всех возможных сочетаний файлов внутри папок. На рисунке для примера один из переборов в консоли выделил.

[image: Перебор всех сочетаний файлов]

Теперь сложность вот в чем: метод библиотеки speechbrain требует передавать ему файлы как строковые аргументы с путями/именами файлов. Скажем, так:

```
score, prediction = verification.verify_files('voices/spk7/spk_7_track_3.wav', 'voices/spk8/spk_8_track_1.wav')
```

Извиняюсь за вопросы начального уровня, но как написать код, который бы:

1. брал кортеж,
2. соединял его с путем к первому файлу, например, `voices/spk7/`,
3. соединял его с путем ко второму файлу (он такой же) - `voices/spk7/`,
4. передавал эти 2 строки в функцию?

Должно получиться нечто такое:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Voices/'):
    for elem in files:
        res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей: [(файл 1, файл 2), (файл 1, файл 3)...(файл 3, файл 4)]
    for tuples in res:         # идем по каждому картежу в списке
        # здесь какой-то код для файла 1 и файла 2:
            verification = SpeakerRecognition.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb", savedir="pretrained_models/spkrec-ecapa-voxceleb")
            score, prediction = verification.verify_files('voices/spk7/spk_7_track_3.wav', 'voices/spk8/spk_8_track_1.wav')
```

Comment: `score, prediction = verification.verify_files(f"voices/spk7/{tuples[0]}", f"voices/spk8/{tuples[1]}")` - так?

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо. Буду делать дальше